# How do I get the "Command Buffer" in Solaris 10?

Tags: solaris

When working on a linx CShell u get the option to press the up / down arrows to select the last command/s typed or the Command Buffer. This even works on Windows.

However this is not functional when working on Solaris, to which i recently switched. I am guessing that the shell is also a CShell.

Please tell me what key combination is required to have this feature on Solaris ?

Answer (score 5):

The default shell in Solaris has command history, but you can also use Bash instead, it's more user friendly. Just type 'bash' (no quotes) at the command line. You can also edit /etc/passwd to make bash your default shell.

Answer (score 3):

The "official" default shell for Solaris is actually `sh`, the original Bourne shell (see [Chapter 10 of the Advanced User Guide](http://docsun.cites.uiuc.edu/sun_docs/C/solaris_9/SUNWabe/ADVOSUG/p34.html) for Solaris for more info). If you'd like to change it to `csh` or `tcsh`—and you're not `root` (it's generally considered bad practice to use anything but `sh` as `root`'s default)—just issue `passwd -e /path/to/shell_of_your_choice <loginname>`. I'm guessing this would probably look like `passwd -e /bin/csh <loginname>`, but you'd probably want to make sure it exists, first.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that it's the Korn shell in which case try <ESC>k.
bash at least will allow you to switch modes with "set -o vi" or "set -o emacs".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the **!!** command, to repeat the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

Use "echo $SHELL" to see what your login shell is.  If it's ksh or bash, try "set -o emacs".  If that works, you'll be able to use ^P to go back a command. ^R lets you search for a command, ^F and ^B to move around within the command.

Answer (score 0):

If you can´t change your default shell, or you just want to try out one that works, you can kick off any other shell from your command line. I recommend you tcsh, which will have good command line editing and history using the arrow keys. Type /bin/tcsh at your prompt to try it out. You can use the earlier responses to change your default shell if you like tcsh. Make sure your have the following in your $HOME/.cshrc file:

set filec
set history=1000 # or some other large number
set autologout=0 # if you are logging in remotely under your account.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You enable history temporarily if you use BASH by typing

```
HISTSIZE=1000
```

which will enable up and down keys and store 1000 commands. After termal disconnetion all history will be gone.

This works on solaris 10.

For permanent solution add these lines to ~/.bashrc

```
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=1000
```